# Understating Persistence of Variables

Tags: c, persistence

I am having trouble understanding why a variable is persisting. My understanding is that a local variable created in a function will no longer exist/hold value once the function exits. Ie it is popped off of the stack. The caveat to this being static or malloc'd variables.

I have an array of data `static struct can_id_info can_id_info[MAX_CAN_ID_MAP_ENTRIES];`. This data cannot be modified by a user. The user does need access to this data so I created two versions of the function.

Original:

```
struct can_id_info dbcppp_map_get(uint32_t can_id) {
    uint16_t i;
    static struct can_id_info temp;
    (void)memset(&temp, 0, sizeof(struct can_id_info));
    for(i=0; i<MAX_CAN_ID_MAP_ENTRIES; i++){
        if(can_id_info[i].can_id == can_id) {
            temp = can_id_info[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

My initial thought was that because `temp` is `static` its memory will persist when the function exits. I then realized this assignment would allow a user to edit the data held within the array. Testing this I now see that the returned value cannot be used to update the original value.

New:

```
struct can_id_info dbcppp_map_get(uint32_t can_id) {
    uint16_t i;
    static struct can_id_info temp;
    (void)memset(&temp, 0, sizeof(struct can_id_info));
    for(i=0; i<MAX_CAN_ID_MAP_ENTRIES; i++){
        if(can_id_info[i].can_id == can_id) {
            memcpy(&temp, &can_id_info[i], sizeof(can_id_info[i]));
            break;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Now I have edited my function to return a copy of the data rather than a temp variable pointing to the data. Now here is where I am confused. Whether I make `temp` `static` or not the data persists when the function exits.

Can someone clarify? How is data meant to persist when a function exits?

Comment: *I then realized this assignment would allow a user to edit the data held within the array* - what array? `temp` does not need to be static. Structs are passed/returned from functions by value.

Comment: @EugeneSh. you should put that an as answer because I did not know that and it explains everything!

Comment: Isn't [this](https://pastebin.com/kusrsYNM) what you're really intending?

Comment: “… a local variable created in a function will no longer exist/hold value once the function exits” is not correct. For an automatic object, when execution of its associated block ends, storage is no longer guaranteed to be reserved for it. That is the **only** thing that is specified to end: The guarantee that it will hold its value. There is no guarantee that the memory will not hold the value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the memory is not guaranteed to hold its value, but saving it in a variable ensures we always have that data. Thank you for this. I was severely mistaken.

Comment: @WhozCraig that is a very clean implementation. I have a find function in my file that I intend to use instead.

Comment: "it is popped off of the stack" - in most cases, it would be more accurate to say that the stack frame is abandoned as-is. But all of that is implementation-defined - the C standard doesn't even contain the word "stack".

Comment: @sj95126 That is really interesting. How does the c standard define the program stack?

Comment: Well, "popped off the stack" merely involves moving the stack pointer. It does not erase the content or something.

Comment: @Michael C standard has no notion of stack. It is not necessary for a fully conforming C implementation.

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you so much everyone. I learned a lot from this!